# Why no Service.onStop method?

Tags: android, android-service

I've read a lot around Android service. As I understand, the lifecycle is:

```
void onCreate() 
    void onStart(Intent intent) 
    ...
void onDestroy()
```

http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

But there's is no onStop method. 
Questions:

- *Why* isn't there a stop method?
- What happens when a stopService request is made on my Service? (from outside, perhaps by Android itself). Can I detect this event?
- I'd like to enforce (or at least verify) that my service is a singleton within a process. How can I do this (or does Android enforce this behind the scenes)?

For context, I have some resources I'd like to allocate and release while the service is running (in a "started"), and another set of resources I'd like to allocate and release while the service is a "created" state.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> As I understand, the lifecycle is:

`onStart()` has been deprecated for a few years. `onStartCommand()` is the current lifecycle method.

> Why isn't there a stop method?

Because there is no need for one.

> What happens when a stopService request is made on my Service?

You will be called with `onDestroy()`.

> Can I detect this event?

You can override `onDestroy()`.

> I'd like to enforce (or at least verify) that my service is a singleton within a process. How can I do this (or does Android enforce this behind the scenes)?

Services are natural singletons. There will be 0 or 1 instance of your service at any given time.

> For context, I have some resources I'd like to allocate and release while the service is running (in a "started"), and another set of resources I'd like to allocate and release while the service is a "created" state.

The "created" state is used both with the command pattern (`startService()` and `onStartCommand()`) and the binding pattern (`bindService()` and `onBind()`). Hence, if you call `startService()`, your service will be purely in the "created" state for hopefully less than a millisecond.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you call bindService with BIND_AUTO_CREATE, onDestroy() won't get called until you unbind

Comment: I observed that `onDestroy()` is not called when device shuts down. Is there any other callback that can be overriden in that case ?

Comment: @fiddler: There is no guarantee that `onDestroy()` will be called, in a few cases (Force Stop, your app crashes, emergency need for system RAM), not just on power down. There is no callback for when Android just terminates your process. *Specifically* with respect to power down, you could try registering a `BroadcastReceiver` for [`ACTION_SHUTDOWN`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN), but I would not count on having time to do anything significant.